# Подскажите пожалуйста, как инициализировать ViewController через storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, uikit

Уважаемые разработчики, помогите пожалуйста )
Не могу понять, как сделать так, что бы можно было добавлять вьюшки через сториборд в моём случае, отображается только заданный кодом background, предполагаю что сториборд игнорируется, но не могу найти решения второй день, фото прикрепляю ниже, Всем хорошего дня!
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM3tt.png)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так, замените в SceneDelegate строчку let newVC = ViewController() на:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
guard let newVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController  else { return }
```

И проставьте Storyboard ID в сториборде ViewController:

[image: Storyboard ID]

Comment: Все работает, спасибо что уделили время!

Comment: Пожалуйста, you are welcome)